# Como utilizar cursor() com dados associados no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, cursor

```
$arrayCarros = [];    

$model = new Carros();

$carros = $model->with('montadoras')->cursor();

foreach($carros as $carros) {
    array_push($arrayCarros, $carro->toArray());
}
```

Executando o código acima, recebo a seguinte saída:

```
        [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'modelo' => 'Fit',
                'ano' => 2015
            ]
        ]
```

Entretanto, se eu executar o código abaixo:

```
$arrayCarros = [];    

$model = new Carros();

$carros = $model->with('montadoras')->toArray();
```

Eu recebo a seguinte saída:

```
        [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'modelo' => 'Fit',
                'ano' => 2015,
                'montadoras' => [
                    'id' => 1,
                    'montadora' => 'Honda'
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

Existe alguma maneira de retornar os dados associados em conjunto a função *cursor* do Laravel?

Comment: Pelo que eu pude perceber ele só carrega mediante chamada do método de relação, e isso não é bom, é melhor trabalhar com `get`, `all`, não achei nada conclusivo nem no site do Laravel, que tem só um pequeno exemplo.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic - Faço jus as suas palavras. O 'cursor()' é um recursos extremamente interessante e útil, principalmente quando estamos trabalhando com grandes volumes de dados. Será uma pena não poder utilizar este recurso e conjunto a dados associados. Irei continuar pesquisando.